# How to generate this report?

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I'm trying to set up a report based on several tables.

I have a table `Actual` that looks like this:

```
+--------+------+
| status | date |
+--------+------+
| 5      | 7/10 |
| 8      | 7/9  |
| 8      | 7/11 |
| 5      | 7/18 |
+--------+------+
```

Table `Targets` looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+--------+------------+
| status | weekEndDate | target | cumulative |
+--------+-------------+--------+------------+
|      5 | 7/12        |      4 |         45 |
|      5 | 7/19        |      5 |         50 |
|      8 | 7/12        |      4 |         45 |
|      8 | 7/19        |      5 |         50 |
+--------+-------------+--------+------------+
```

Grouping the `Actual` records by which `Targets.weekEndDate` they fall under, I have the following aggregate query `GroupActual`:

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+------------+
| weekEndDate |    status  | weeklyTarget | actual | cumulative |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+------------+
| 7/12        | 5          |            4 |      1 |         45 |
| 7/12        | 8          |            4 |      2 |         41 |
| 7/19        | 5          |            5 |      1 |         50 |
| 7/19        | 8          |            4 |        |         45 |
+-------------+------------+--------------+--------+------------+
```

I'm trying to create this report:

```
+--------+------------+------+------+
| status | category   | 7/12 | 7/19 | ...etc for every weekEndDate entry in Targets
+--------+------------+------+------+
| 5      | actual     |   1  |    1 |
| 5      | target     |   4  |    5 |
| 5      | cumulative |  45  |   50 |
+--------+------------+------+------+
| 8      | actual     |   2  |      |
| 8      | target     |   4  |    5 |
| 8      | cumulative |  45  |   50 |
+--------------+------+------+------+
```

I can use a crosstab query to make the date columns, but I'm not sure how to have rows for "actual", "target", and "cumulative".  They aren't values in the same table, which means (I think) that a crosstab query won't be useful for this breakdown.  Should I try to change `GroupActual` so that it puts the data in the shape I'm looking for?  Kind of confused as to where to go next with this...

EDIT: I've made some headway on the crosstabs as per PowerUser's solution, but I'm having trouble with the one for `Target`. I modified the wizard's generated SQL in an attempt to get what I want but it's not working out.  I used a version of `GroupActual` that only has the `weekEndDate`,`status`, and `weeklyTarget` columns; here's the SQL:

```
TRANSFORM weeklyTarget
SELECT status
FROM TargetStatus_forCrosstab_Target
GROUP BY status,weeklyTarget
PIVOT Format([weekEndDate],"Short Date");
```

Comment: Am I getting this right; you need Actual from the query GroupActual, and Target and Cumulative from the table Targets?

Comment: @JohnnyBones, yes, for each date and status in Targets I need to get the count of how many Actual entries with that status have a date within a week before that date, which I've done with `GroupActual`.  The challenging part is getting the Actual counts in one row and the targets in the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  The problem is that you can't do this all in a single crosstab.  You need to make 3 crosstabs (one for 'actual', one for 'target', and one for 'cumulative'), then make a Union query to combine them all.

Additional Tip: In your individual crosstabs, add a Sort column.  Your 'actual' crosstab will have a Sort value of 1, 'Target' will have a Sort value of 2, and 'Cumulative' will have 3.  That way, when you union them together, you can get them all in the right order.

Comment: I've got the crosstab for `Actual` worked out, but I'm having trouble with `Target`, because these values don't need to be summed--they just need to be laid out on each date column, grouped by `status`.  I'll post the SQL above.

Comment: Never mind, I got it.  Using a sum worked fine because I'm grouping based on `weekEndDate` and there's only one value per date.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to think of how to say just that. Glad to be of help.